# Keep Pow disabled by default when Booting OSX

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rack-pow

I use my MacBook for web development with PHP and Ruby on Rails, so I have installed MAMP and Posgres.app and Pow. When I turn on my Mac and go to localhost, it automatically shows an Pow Info, so in case I need to do something with PHP I have to turn off pow, turn on MAMP and then go to localhost.

Is there a way to keep Pow disable when I turn on my Mac so then I could choose which one of Pow or MAMP am I going to use?

Comment: Look into [Powder](https://github.com/Rodreegez/powder). It works for me.

Comment: I'm taking a look into it and it seems great! however I don't see an option to keep pow 'down' by default. Do I need to use 'powder down' each time I boot my Mac?

Comment: Sorry, it's been over a year since I configured my Pow server via Powder, so I forgot the details. You'll also need Lunchy on the Mac side to control launchctl. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959596/how-can-i-stop-the-pow-server-from-starting-up-at-computer-boot-os-x).

Comment: But I guess if I use Lunchy there's no need to use powder, am I right? I could control Pow just using Lunchy's start and stop.